# How to copy QWidget through pointers in C++

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qtcore, qobject

My goal is this:

```
QWidget *p = new QSpinBox(0); // This can be any type of QWidget.

QWidget* Get()
{
  /*
  Here using p, I need to return a NEW object of QSpinBox or whatever 
  the qwidget assigned to p. I can't return p because it will be deleted
  after this method, so the next time p would be empty.
  */
}
```

It's used for the QStyledItemDelegates::createEditor() method. The widget returned from get will be deleted when the delegate editing is done.

Comment: You need to copy the object that `s` points to, not just the pointer.

Comment: Why will it be deleted after this method?  That sounds like an error to me; GUI objects do not normally have lifetimes which obey scope.  (That's one of the reasons why they are always dynamically allocated.)

Comment: It's used for QStyledItemDelegates createEditor() method. The widget returned from Get will be deleted when the delegate editing is done.

Comment: why you need a copy? Probably you have a code which creates this spin box so use same code to create a new spin box which you will return.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're more interested in the data that the editor contains more that the editor itself. Rather copy the data and let the Model-View-Delegate architecture continue to function as designed

Answer (score 3):

All `QObjects` are not copyable by definition. See [its header file](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/57756e72adf2081137b97f0e689dd16c770d10b1%3asrc/corelib/kernel/qobject.h#L309).
Same applies to [QSpinBox](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/57756e72adf2081137b97f0e689dd16c770d10b1%3asrc/gui/widgets/qspinbox.h#L121).

Reason is simple cloning of signal slots memory management could lead to unpredictable results, so it was disabled by design.

Comment: I am with Marek in here: `I need to return a NEW object of QSpinBox or what ever the qwidget assigned to p.`

Comment: yes title is crappy, you can fix it. But he clearly ask to cone an object which he already have, to pass it as editor by `QStyledItemDelegates::createEditor`.

Comment: @LaszloPapp - the question should be about how to structure his data instead.

Comment: @ddriver: you are free to submit your own question.

Comment: @LaszloPapp - I don't have a question, he is simply asking the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

The copy of a pointer to an object doesn't copy the object in any way. In Qt the copy of `QObject` derived classes is indeed disabled, but you can copy pointers to the object around as much as you want, or until you run out of memory...

Due to the design of Qt `QObject` derived classes have unique identities. This means they must not be copied, at least in the rational sense of the term. You could however write your own "clone function" that creates a new instance with unique identity and applies all of the properties of the object `p` points to to the new instance. E.g. you can fake it to a certain amount but don't expect to get a copy functionally identical to the original. If you want to get a fully functionally identical clone, you will have to implement your own signal and slot mechanism instead of using the one provided by Qt.

You CAN indeed return `p` - but it will point to nothing if you call delete on it. Keep in mind returning `p` will simply copy the pointer, it has nothing to do with the actual object pointed to. `p` is just a number.

Edit:

At a deeper look at the "reflection facilities" provided by Qt, it looks like you could get signals and slots to clone, but it is not pretty - you have to query every `QMetaMethod` of the `QMetaObject` associated with the particular instance to find the signals, but then you hit a brick wall - you will have to resort to using private APIs (a big no-no in 99.9999% of the cases) in order to query for the signal receivers in order to connect the new copy to them as well. Definitely not something that was intended to be done. In short, you need to rethink your strategy at getting the problem solved.

Overall, as I mentioned in the comments, your problem seems to be bad design, and even though it is technically possible to make the bad design work, you'd be much better if you simply improve your design and avoid arduous if not even masochistic endeavors.

Comment: The OP explicitly mentioned that the pointer gets deleted, which means you will get a dangling pointer. That will blow up as a crash at the first dereference. In this thread, apparently only you did not get it so far. Even the deleted answers got that bit right.

Comment: @LaszloPapp - that would only make what he asks about technically impossible. It doesn't make your answer relevant...

Comment: No, it is not technically impossible. I gave several ways. One is the object tree and other is the smart pointers.

Comment: @LaszloPapp - several ways? I don't see not one that yields in a functional copy. Copy/pasing that cloning is a complex operation doesn't really qualify for a solution to the problem... I know cloning a human organism is a complex operation too, alas that doesn't allow me to clone one :)

Answer (score 0):

`s` is a pointer, which can be copied and modified at will; modifications to the copy will never affect the original.  If what you meant was in fact the object which `s` referred to, then it's sufficient to provide it with a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator; depending on the content of the class, the compiler may have generated these for you.

Depending on the content, it's also possible that the compiler generated versions don't do what you need.

Given the name of the class, I suspect that it is part of Qt.  In that case, check the documentation. It may support cloning, in which case, what you probably want is a clone.